# How many ways to arrange 12 identical apples and five distinct oranges in a row so no two oranges are side by side?

Tags: combinatorics

My first intuition to solve this problem was to use the separator technique with the apples acting as separators.

$$_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_$$

Since there are now 13 blank spaces for the oranges to be distributed, I chose:

$$c(13,5)*5!$$

I first select the possible spaces for the oranges to be placed, and then I make them distinct. Would this answer be correct? I'm a little unsure about the `c(13,5)`.

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, this is right.